# Is it possible to show action button in lightning outside of dropdown icon?

Tags: lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Currently buttons are visible within this drop down icon

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to show these buttons directly like this ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've attached a screen shot.  Basically you just:

1. Click Edit Page to edit the Lightning Page
2. Click on the Highlights Panel Component to select it
3. Then you should see the Visible Action Buttons box on the right side

[image: Action button]

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the lightning page > click on "Highlights Panel" > update "Visible Action Buttons (desktop only)"

[image]